# get_template_directory_uri does not seem to work when defining WP_CONTENT_DIR

Tags: themes, wp-config, bug

I have defined in my config:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/somedirectory' );
```

after [Codex: Editing WP Config](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder)

BUT `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` prints out:

```
http://dev.domain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
```

Even though it should print out

```
http://dev.domain.com/somedirectory/themes/mytheme
```

Has anyone else experienced this or know of a fix?

Comment: As @user51755 said, you need to define  `WP_CONTENT_URL` too :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how i set my content directory in wp-config.php

```
// ========================
// Custom Content Directory
// ========================
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/somedir' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/somedir' );
```